# How to create a curved tiles effect in adobe illustration

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This curved tiles shape was created in adobe illustration:

[image: grid effect in adobe illustration]

How can I recreate it?

Answer (score 5):

- Draw a rectangle, long and short.
- Choose Object > Path > Split Into Grid and add rows and columns with gutters to create a series of smaller rectangles and click OK. 
   [image: rectangles]
- Choose Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp. From here it's a bit of a guessing game. Adjust settings to try and get close to the basic overall shape you want. Click OK when you're close.
  [image: distort]
- Now use the Free Transform Tool to rotate and size the Envelope to better batch your desired position and size. 
  [image: free transform]
- Now simply choose Object > Expand and you can delete any unwanted pieces.
  [image: deleted]